# Get Signal strength of client connected to esp8266 AP

Tags: at-command, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

Using esp8266 as an access point so that the other mobiles could connect with the esp8266, Want to get the client's info like ip, mac and rssi, this could be done by the command AT+CWLAP. I had programmed the esp in Arduino, want to execute the command in Arduino code, have no clue.

Is there any way to get this solved?
Or which is the better option to access the clients' information(ip, mac and rssi)?

Comment: Tried this? AT+CWLAP="<your AP>"

Comment: @cagdas, think  you haven't got my question, by the way I tried it to get the RSSI of the AP